# How to specify OpenAPI for binary download in angular

Tags: angular, swagger-codegen

I have a method to download a binary file. This currently has the following spec in openapi.yaml:

```
  /processing/getZippedReports:
    post:
      tags:
      - ProcessingRest
      description: Get the reports
      operationId: getZippedReports
      requestBody:
        description: The list of items for which to get the HTML
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: array
              items:
                type: string
        required: true
      responses:
        200:
          description: file with zipped reports
          content:
            application/octet-stream: {}
```

The generated typescript-angular code contains this call  to httpClient:

```
return this.httpClient.post<any>(`${this.configuration.basePath}/processing/getZippedReports`,
    requestBody,
    {
        withCredentials: this.configuration.withCredentials,
        headers: headers,
        observe: observe,
        reportProgress: reportProgress
    }
);
```

This way, angular seems unable to receive the binary content. I had to change the httpClient, use the non-type-variable signature of `post` and add `responseType: blob` to the parameters

```
return this.httpClient.post(`${this.configuration.basePath}/processing/getZippedReports`,
    requestBody,
    {
        withCredentials: this.configuration.withCredentials,
        headers: headers,
        observe: 'response',
        responseType: 'blob',
        reportProgress: reportProgress
    }
);
```

Is this a bug / missing feature in Swagger codegen or should I change the openapi definition to get working angular code?

Comment: Try replacing empty response schema `{}` with a schema with `type: string` + `format: binary`. Does this help?

Comment: Yes, this indeed changes the signature of the HttpClient post request. Please post as answer, so I can accept

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To indicate that the response is a binary file, use a schema with `type: string` with `format: binary`.

```yaml
          content:
            application/octet-stream:
              schema:
                type: string
                format: binary
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue as the original poster. I've tried this @Helen, as it's marked as the accepted answer, but still doesn't include `responseType: 'blob'` in generated code. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

It seems there is a `x-is-file` Vendor Extensions, i found it in the sourcecode, but no docs about it. Which leads to correct `responseType` definition in the controllerService.ts

```
        "responses": {
            "default": {
                "x-is-file": true,
                "description": "default response",
                "content": {
                    "application/octet-stream": {
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "file"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

@wutzebaer was right about `x-is-file`

This is the definition in swagger 2.0

```
     responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          x-is-file: true
          schema:
            type: string
            format: binary
```

This generates

```
return this.httpClient.request('post',`${this.basePath}/member/generate_report_download`,
            {
                body: body,
                params: queryParameters,
                responseType: "blob", <--- Correct response type
                withCredentials: this.configuration.withCredentials,
                headers: headers,
                observe: observe,
                reportProgress: reportProgress
            }
        );
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. I am pretty sure that `x-is-*` and `x-has-*` properties are internals and should not be put in the openapi specification. They are set up by codegen according to other properties. This is a workaround against a bug in swagger-codegen.